# Evaluation of Complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
|e^{irz}-1|\leqq re^{|y|r} \text{ for } z=x+iy, |z|=1, r>0.
\end{equation}

My attempt

\begin{align}
|e^{irz}-1|
&=|e^{-ry} \cos(rx) -1 + ie^{-ry} \sin(rx)| \\
&=\sqrt{(e^{-ry} \cos(rx) -1)^2+(e^{-ry} \sin(rx))^2} \\
&=\sqrt{e^{-2ry}-2e^{-ry}\cos(rx)+1} \\
&\leqq \sqrt{e^{-2ry}+2e^{-ry}+1} \\
&=\sqrt{(e^{-ry}+1)^2} \\
&=|e^{-ry}+1|.
\end{align}

But this doesn't seem to work.
I would like you to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof: Please note that, by $\textbf{Newton-Leibniz formula}$,

> You can refer https://www.oulu.fi/sites/default/files/151/complex_book.pdf    Page73

$$e^{irz}-1=\int_{0}^{r}ize^{iuz}du.$$
So
\begin{align*}
|e^{irz}-1|
&\leq |iz|r\cdot\max_{u\in[0,r]}|e^{iuz}|\\
&=|iz|r\cdot\max_{u\in[0,r]}e^{\text{Re}(iuz)}\\
&=r\cdot\max_{u\in[0,r]}e^{-uy}\\
&\leq r\cdot\max_{u\in[0,r]}e^{u|y|}\\
&=re^{r|y|}.
\end{align*}

Autually, there is a lemma like this:

> If $a,b$ are real numbers and $s=\sigma+it(\sigma>0)$,
> then
> $$e^{bs}-e^{as}\leq |s||b-a| e^{\max\{a,b\}\cdot\sigma}.$$
> $$e^{bs}-e^{as}=\int_{a}^{b}se^{xs}dx.$$
> So (W.L.G we suppose $a<b$)
> \begin{align*}
> |e^{bs}-e^{as}|
> &\leq |s||b-a|\max_{x\in[a,b]}|e^{xs}|\\
> &=|s||b-a|\max_{x\in[a,b]}e^{\text{Re}(xs)}\\
> &=|s||b-a|\max_{x\in[a,b]}e^{x\sigma}\\
> &=|s||b-a| e^{\max\{a,b\}\cdot\sigma}.
> \end{align*}

Comment: @ Riemann What is "N-L formula" ? Could you tell me the official name?

Comment: @EPA  Newton-Leibniz formula, I fixed it!

Comment: @ Riemann Thank you.

Comment: @EPA You can refer https://www.oulu.fi/sites/default/files/151/complex_book.pdf    Page73